# Is it possible to get json values as list from array of json in Postgres?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I use Postgresql 10 and suppose, that I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(id int8 NOT NULL, data jsonb);
```

And inserted such values:

```
insert into test_table(id, data)
values (1, '{"external": [{"internal_1": "value_1", "internal_2": "some_value"}]}'),
       (2, '{"external": [{"internal_1": "value_2", "internal_2": "another_value"}]}'),
       (3, '{"external": [{"internal_1": "value_1", "internal_2": "other_value"}]}');
```

The table after all:

```
id|                                data                                     |
--|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
1 |{"external": [{"internal_1": "value_1", "internal_2": "some_value"}]}    |
2 |{"external": [{"internal_1": "value_2", "internal_2": "another_value"}]} |
3 |{"external": [{"internal_1": "value_1", "internal_2": "other_value"}]}   |
```

**The problem is that I need to have all internal values as an array**

I tried the following query:

```
select data -> 'external'
from test_table;
```

and the result is:

```
?column?                                                         |
-----------------------------------------------------------------|
[{"internal_1": "value_1", "internal_2": "some_value"}]          |
[{"internal_1": "value_2", "internal_2": "another_value"}]       |
[{"internal_1": "value_1", "internal_2": "other_value"}]         |
```

But finally I need to have internal values as text array for each table row. Something like that:

```
?column?                       |
-------------------------------|
[value_1, some_value]          |
[value_2, another_value]       |
[value_1, other_value]         |
```

**Is it possible to write such query using postgres json functions and operators?**

**UPD!!**
*Number of internal keys could be different (internal_1, ..., internal_n) and we don’t know in advance names of keys (in my case they are: internal_1 and internal_2)*

Comment: Yes, it is. Did you [take a look at them](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)?

Comment: What do you want the result to look like when there are multiple objects in the arrays? Do you expect the objects to have keys that are not `internal_…` (and if yes, what to do with them)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be splitting the elements through going deep into each key individually in an explicit manner, and then using `jsonb_build_array()` function  :

```
SELECT jsonb_build_array(
       (data ->> 'external')::jsonb -> 0 ->> 'internal_1',
       (data ->> 'external')::jsonb -> 0 ->> 'internal_2')
  FROM test_table
```

Or more dynamically (for the cases of having more or less internal keys) `jsonb_each_text()` might be used within a CROSS JOIN query to extract each key and then `jsonb_agg()` might be applied to combine them within arrays :

```
SELECT id, 
       jsonb_agg(js.value)
  FROM test_table
 CROSS JOIN jsonb_each_text( ((data ->> 'external')::jsonb -> 0)::jsonb) AS js
 GROUP BY id
 ORDER BY id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e99fabd1e10ed39b3e199b84a08ef5cf)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My fault, I forgot to say that number of internal keys could be different (internal_1, ..., internal_n) and we don’t know in advance names of keys (in my case they are: internal_1 and internal_2). Tomorrow I’ll update my question with new terms.

Comment: Thank you very much, @barbaros-Özhan! That works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

The following query should to what you want:

```
select json_build_array(data#>>'{external,0, internal_1}', data#>>'{external,0, internal_2}')
from test_table;
```

The idea is to use the `json_build_array` function to create an array and them you need to select each element that will be part of it, a convenient way to do it is by using the `#>'{json_path}'` so you select the elements using a json path.

Source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-json.html

SQLFiddle to test it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5c4d2/19

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My fault, I forgot to say that number of internal keys could be different (internal_1, ..., internal_n) and we don’t know in advance names of keys (in my case they are: internal_1 and internal_2). Tomorrow I’ll update my question with new terms.